# Convert dictionary with values that are long numbers into values that are regular integers

Tags: python, dictionary, long-integer

Given something like this:

```
yesterday = {'facebook_adgroups': [4634L], 'google_third_party_tags': [1790L]}
```

I want to convert the values that happen to be in a list/long format, into just numbers so that I can run some calculations later. I keep running into a few different errors, or the changes are just not 'taking'. Here was my last attempt:

```
for k, v in yesterday.iteritems():
    i = 0
    print v[0]
    yesterday.values()[i] = v[0]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following tweak does what you are asking:

When you just assign the value to the corresponding key, it preserves the `long` characteristic:

```
yesterday = {'facebook_adgroups': [4634L], 'google_third_party_tags': [1790L]}

for k, v in yesterday.iteritems():
    i = 0
    print v[0]
    yesterday[k] = v[0]
    i += 1

print yesterday
```

Results in

```
4634
1790
{'facebook_adgroups': 4634L, 'google_third_party_tags': 1790L}
```

Note the values still have the `L`. But when I change the assignment:

```
yesterday[k] = int(v[0])
```

The output becomes

```
{'facebook_adgroups': 4634, 'google_third_party_tags': 1790}
```

I will freely admit this is "not very Pythonic" - but it does appear to do the job.

Upon re-reading your question, it appears I answered the question as stated in the title - but now that I look more closely it's not clear that this is what you were struggling with.

I would strongly caution you that if you started out with key/value pairs, trying to go to a numerical index is fraught with danger. Things may not be in the order you thought, items may be missing, etc. Unless you specifically assign in a known order, with defaults for missing values, this will go wrong one day - and you will be searching for hours to find the bug. Better to do something like

```
yNum[0] = yesterday['facebook_adgroups']
yNum[1] = yesterday['google_third_party_tags']
```

etc. Perhaps with `int()` around it if you want to force the type.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but is there no 'safe' way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Victor - I don't see how you can - if you don't know the order of keys (or which ones are present) then you _have_ to confirm each key individually. If you know exactly what keys will be present you could make sure they are sorted alphabetically, then iterate over the sorted list. But the whole point of key/value pairs is _flexibility_ - when you remove that, your code becomes more brittle. And one day it will break. Trust me on that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think longs have anything to do with it: IIUC, you simply want to turn the values, which are currently lists of one element, into the elements themselves.  You can use a dict comprehension for this:

```
>>> yesterday = {'facebook_adgroups': [4634L], 'google_third_party_tags': [1790L]}
>>> yesterday = {k: v[0] for k,v in yesterday.iteritems()}
>>> yesterday
{'facebook_adgroups': 4634L, 'google_third_party_tags': 1790L}
```

This line of your code:

```
    yesterday.values()[i] = v[0]
```

won't "take" because `yesterday.values()` constructs a new list, separate from the dictionary, containing the dictionary values.  `[i]` selects the `i-th` element of that new temporary list, and then you set that to `v[0]`.  The original `yesterday` dictionary is unaffected.  If you'd mutated the element, though, e.g. appending to the list, that change would have showed up in the dictionary because the elements in the `.values()` list are the very same objects in the dictionary.

(Note also that because dictionaries aren't ordered, referring to elements by index like this is going to get you into trouble, even if it seems to work sometimes.)

Answer (score 2):

DSM's answer shows what you can do to fix your problem (use a dict comprehension), but I thought I'd explain a bit more about why your current code doesn't work.

The key line is:

```
yesterday.values()[i] = v[0]
```

This doesn't do anything useful. In Python 2, `dict.values()` returns a new list with a copy of the dictionary's current values. Mutating that list does not do anything to change the dictionary. (In Python 3, `dict.values()` returns a "view" object which is directly tied to the dictionary, but it is neither indexable or mutable so trying to assign to an index within it will raise an exception.)

An alternative would be to change the value directly in the dictionary:

```
yesterday[k] = v[0] # or use int(v[0]) if you still need to get rid of the longs
```

Comment: Helpful explanation of "why your code has no effect". Last line looks a lot like the approach I was taking...

Comment: @Floris: yep, I saw your version go up just as I was about to post my own, but I hoped my explanation might still be helpful. It looks like DSM's has edited in roughly the same explanation though, so I guess we are all thinking alike.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation here. Helpful and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I cant really get the point behind your question. But as per my understanding of your problem,

```
yesterday = {'facebook_adgroups': [4634L], 'google_third_party_tags': [1790L]}

for k,v in yesterday.items():
    print '%s : %s' % (k, map(int,v)[0])

for k,v in yesterday.items():
    print '%s : %s' % (k, int(v[0]))
```

Both the above ways will provide you with the same output

output:

```
facebook_adgroups : 4634
google_third_party_tags : 1790
facebook_adgroups : 4634
google_third_party_tags : 1790
```